# Printing Array with recurse in java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

i want to print an array with recurse in java, but the only parameter is the array itself. is it possible?

```
public static void printintArr(int[] a)
```

Comment: Yes, as long as you can store the current index as a field. This is not recommended though - passing the current index as a parameter is much neater.

Comment: You could also print the first element, create another array containing all the other elements, and call your method recursively with this "sub-array". This is of course a stupid solution, but the requirement is stupid as well.

Comment: @JBNizet I suppose that would also be the answer to "I have too much CPU power, how do I print an array in `O(n^2)`?".  Although, funnily enough, this _is_ the solution for a cons-list.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. This is one way to do it:

```
public static void print(int[] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println(array[0]);
        int[] next = new int[array.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(array, 1, next, 0, array.length - 1);
        print(next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printArr(array);
}

public static void printArr(int[] a) {
    if (a != null && a.length > 0) {
        System.out.println(a[0]);
        // Call the function printArr with the full array, without the first element
        printArr(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length));
    }
}
```

You have to import **java.util.Arrays**

Output :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

From end:

```
void printer(int[] input){
   if(input.length > 0){
       System.out.println(input[input.length-1]);
       printer(Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length-1));
   }
}
```

From start:

```
void printer(int[] input){
   if(input.length > 0){
       System.out.println(input[0]);
       printer(Arrays.copyOfRange(input, 1, input.length));
   }
}
```

Comment: If input.length == 0 this will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions on here so far all involve copying the entire array minus one element repeatedly. This is exceptionally slow. They run in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time.

There is a way to do this in *O(n)* time, but with a `List`:

```
public void print(final List<?> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
    print(list.subList(1, list.size()));
}
```

Because `subList` is a *view* and not a *copy*, this method would run in *O(n)* time as you would expect. Sadly is takes a `List` and not an array.

Luckily there is a very easy way to get an `Object` array into a `List`:

```
final String[] data = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(data);
```

This does not copy the array, it simply returns a view of the array as a `List`. Sadly this does not work for primitive arrays. For that you need to do something like:

```
final int[] data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Arrays.stream(data).boxed().collect(toList());
```

Which does require a copy.

I would point out though that an *O(n)* copy followed by an *O(n)* print is still going to be much more efficient than a single *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* operation.